# Disparity between date/time calculations in C# versus Delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, datetime

Delphi:

```
SecondsBetween(StrToDateTime('16/02/2009 11:25:34 p.m.'), StrToDateTime('1/01/2005 12:00:00 a.m.'));

130289133
```

C#:

```
TimeSpan span = DateTime.Parse("16/02/2009 11:25:34 p.m.").Subtract(DateTime.Parse("1/01/2005 12:00:00 a.m."));

130289134
```

It's not consistent either. Some dates will add up the same, ie..

```
TimeSpan span = DateTime.Parse("16/11/2011 11:25:43 p.m.").Subtract(DateTime.Parse("1/01/2005 12:00:00 a.m."));

SecondsBetween(StrToDateTime('16/11/2011 11:25:43 p.m.'), StrToDateTime('1/01/2005 12:00:00 a.m.'));

both give

216905143
```

The total amount of seconds is actually being used to encode data, and I'm trying to port the application to C#, so even one second completely throws everything off.

Can anybody explain the disparity? And is there a way to get c# to match delphi?

Edit: In response to suggestions that it might be leap second related: Both date ranges contain the same amount of leap seconds (2), so you would expect a mismatch for both. But instead we're seeing inconsistency

```
16/02/2009 - 1/01/2005 = Delphi and C# calculate a different total seconds

16/11/2011 - 1/01/2005 = They calculate the same total seconds
```

Comment: Interesting problem but you _should_ ask a question.

Comment: Perhaps the two systems deal with [leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) differently?

Comment: @Austin Salonen I added the question part for you :P

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for `SecondsBetween`?

Comment: Are you trying encoding the values instead of parsing an string? I ask you because I test the code using this sentence `SecondsBetween(EncodeDateTime(2009,2,16,23,25,34,0), EncodeDateTime(2005,1,1,0,0,0,0))` and in both languages the result is the same (130289134
).

Comment: I think Delphi calculates the result incorrectly: the first diff should end in 34, because you are subtracting from <something>:34 a time/date with minutes and seconds set to zero. So now I would try to find out if the difference happens on or around a particular day. Write a loop that moves the start date by one day progressively, until the diff ends in 34. Then try to isolate the hour and the minute when it happens. This may not give you an answer, but it may provide a clue.

Comment: @RRUZ I tried this just now, and it still shows 130289133. My friend who uses the newer version of Delphi gets the correct value.. so I think this must be a problem with the 2007 version only.

Comment: @AustinSalonen http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.SecondsBetween is the best I can find

Comment: @NoPyGod, you are right I test in Delphi XE2 and the result match with C#, but not with Delphi 2007.

Comment: @NoPyGod i found this [QC 59310](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=59310) the bug was fixed in Delphi XE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue it seems related to this [QC 59310](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=59310), the bug was fixed in Delphi XE.

Comment: Given this, how would I emulate this bug in C#? I am trying to port an application and if I'm one second off it throws the whole decoding part of the application into disarray. Thanks for finding this information, very helpful.

Comment: @NoPyGod You cannot eliminate it in the C#, because it is on Delphi's side; you can re-introduce it there, but it may be too much of a hack. Try using "days between" (assuming there is such a method), and then calculate the difference between two date-less times manually.

Answer (score 0):

One will likely deal with [Leap Seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second). However, .NET does not as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Both date ranges contain the same amount of leap seconds, and yet one of them is calculated correctly.

Comment: @NoPyGod, if one accounts for leap seconds and the other does not, it would result in a discrepancy.

Comment: I compared the results in both languages for two different date ranges. In one case the results matched. Both date ranges contain the same number of leap seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention how you convert the c# TimeSpan into a number. The TotalSeconds property is a floating point value - perhaps it's a rounding problem in the double to int conversion?

Comment: just with a regular cast (int)

Comment: The value as a double is still incorrect. But you're absolutely right, I shouldn't have omitted that detail.