# How to emulate the Delphi 2007 SecondsBetween function in C#?

Tags: c#, delphi, datetime, delphi-2007

This is a follow up to a previous question:  [Disparity between date/time calculations in C# versus Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529476/disparity-between-date-time-calculations-in-c-sharp-versus-delphi)

I am porting an enterprise application written in Delphi to C#. The application uses a very rudimentary form of encryption for storing the text files it generates. This encryption is based around the Delphi SecondsBetween command, which returns the number of seconds between two dates.

The problem for me is that in the older version of Delphi (the one I'm porting from), there is a bug with the SecondsBetween command which causes it to return values that are off by one - **but only about 50% of the time**

The bug is a rounding bug. Delphi originally used Trunc instead of Round. See more detail here - http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=59310

Here is the code to demonstrate the problem:

Delphi:

```
SecondsBetween(StrToDateTime('16/02/2009 11:25:34 p.m.'), StrToDateTime('1/01/2005 12:00:00 a.m.'));

130289133
```

C#:

```
TimeSpan span = DateTime.Parse("16/02/2009 11:25:34 p.m.").Subtract(DateTime.Parse("1/01/2005 12:00:00 a.m."));

130289134
```

What I'd like to do is figure out how I can emulate this buggy behavior in C# so that I can read/write the text files written by the Delphi application.

Comment: I trust you are going to take this opportunity to move towards a robust encryption in future releases

Comment: Why don't you write a converter in D2007, store the resulting text files in a better format. This will ensure you are doing the encryption/decryption correct and spare future mishaps.

Comment: Wow. Floating point error in your encryption algorithm. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is translation of the required functions (SpanOfNowAndThen, SecondSpan) to replicate the Delphi 2007 [`SecondsBetween`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DateUtils.SecondsBetween) function.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace D2007SecondsBetween
{
    class Program
    {
      const double HoursPerDay   = 24;
      const double MinsPerHour   = 60;
      const double SecsPerMin    = 60;
      const double MSecsPerSec   = 1000;
      const double MinsPerDay    = HoursPerDay * MinsPerHour;
      const double SecsPerDay    = MinsPerDay * SecsPerMin;

        static double SpanOfNowAndThen(Double ANow, Double AThen)
        {
          if (ANow < AThen)
            return AThen - ANow;
          else
            return ANow - AThen;
        }


        static double SecondSpan(Double ANow, Double AThen)
        {
         return  SecsPerDay * SpanOfNowAndThen(ANow, AThen);
        }

        static int SecondsBetween(DateTime ANow, DateTime AThen)
        {
          return (int)Math.Truncate(SecondSpan(ANow.ToOADate(), AThen.ToOADate()));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TimeSpan span ;            
            span = DateTime.Parse("16/02/2009 23:25:34").Subtract(DateTime.Parse("1/01/2005 00:00:00"));
            Console.WriteLine(span.TotalSeconds);//returns 130289134
            Console.WriteLine(SecondsBetween(DateTime.Parse("16/02/2009 23:25:34"), DateTime.Parse("1/01/2005 00:00:00")));//returns 130289133

            span = DateTime.Parse("16/11/2011 23:25:43").Subtract(DateTime.Parse("1/01/2005 00:00:00"));
            Console.WriteLine(span.TotalSeconds);//returns 216948343
            Console.WriteLine(SecondsBetween(DateTime.Parse("16/11/2011 23:25:43"), DateTime.Parse("1/01/2005 00:00:00")));//returns 216948343

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: However, it is conceivable that this code will fail for a tiny number of cases. I would expect the treatment of floating point arithmetic to differ between .net and D2007. Intermediates may be 80 bit in one and 64 bit in the other. And so on. Without studying actual machine language it's impossible to be sure and even then it would depend on what the jitter does. It was folly to rely on floating point for encryption.

Comment: That's the best answer I've ever had on StackOverflow, and it's the second time you've really helped me RRUZ. Thank you. I will now have to test it like crazy.

Comment: Upvoted for crazy dedication to helping people.  No way I would have dived in here.

Answer (score 3):

I think in your situation I would simply compile the faulty Delphi routine into a DLL and use p/invoke to call it from the C#. I'd include a call to set the 8087 control word before the calc, and one to restore it to the callers value afterwards. This would be the lowest risk approach that I can think of.

Comment: Why would you set the 8087 control word (I'm not even sure what this means) if the code is isolated in a delphi dll?

Comment: Because the C# code will likely use a different 8087CW from the value expected by Delphi. The system doesn't manage this particular part of the processor context for you and so you need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

How about artificially adding 0.5 seconds to the term being subtracted (right side) and then truncating `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds` to an `int` value?  Perhaps this would work:

```
int BuggySecondsBetween(DateTime left, DateTime right)
{
    TimeSpan actual = left - right;
    TimeSpan buggyResult = actual - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5d);
    return (int)buggyResult.TotalSeconds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The business risk sounds very high, and unfortunately there's naff-all information from Delphi about how this bug behaves internally.  Writing and unit-testing a compensatory method in C# can't be guaranteed to mitigate the issue at all times.

Unless a knowledgeable soul chimes in with specific details, might it be possible for you to recompile and rollout your original Delphi app using version 15.0.3729.28755 (with the bug fix)?

The other possibility is a 'big bang' rollout for your C# port to completely replace the Delphi one, although that can be more stressful in terms of training and staff support.

Good luck with this - it's a tricky problem.

Comment: It's not high risk, it's a relatively basic application with a very small team.

Comment: Application and teamsize not withstanding, I'm assuming if the application starts writing mis-encoded data to disk due to an incorrect time stamp it will be a major business problem?  If not can you just rollout the C# app to slowly fix the bug?  I appreciate this may involve running an overnight process to decrypt-and-re-encrypt all files encoded with the Delphi bug.

Comment: I've examined all of the risks mommy, now can I please have a solution :)

Comment: Unless you have more details on how exactly the bug behaves, you can't emulate it.  I hope someone can give you that information.  Good luck.